# Geometry Nodes // Rotate instances separately based on rotation and location of Empty Sphere

Tags: node-editor, geometry

[image]I have a grid with instances. I then added an Empty Sphere and want to rotate all of the instances 90° which are within the range of the Empty Sphere.
I figured out to rotate all of the instances at once, but can't figure out how to rotate each instance separately at the location of the Sphere.

[image]

Comment: You can also have a [smooth falloff](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/870021681849204797/1063530284617846925/blender_8axgUrp9aR.mp4) - [node setup](https://i.imgur.com/a7eTs5l.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Geometry Proximity node**.
(You will have to parent a single vert to the empty as the node works with geometry only)

Then using **Compare: Less Than** to get a boolean output to use as the selection for the **Rotate Instances node**, you can rotate the instances to 90 deg within the threshold you set in te Compare node.

Now I have used the Empty Display Size as driver to control the threshold. But you can do the same with the scale instead. That will just be a little bit of more work to do.

[image]
[image]